# WebGL Marquee/Lasso Selection Tool

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl, shader

So I have a WebGL model viewer (one model made of lots of different objects), in which I have implemented a lasso/marquee selection box.  That is, the user can click to drag a rectangle on the screen, and everything inside the rectangle gets selected.  It selects not just visible objects, but everything in the model that is within the bounds of the rectangle.

I have to do this for 2 cases: partial and full selection.

**Full Selection:** only objects that are *completely* inside the rectangle will get selected.

**Partial Selection:**  *any* object that has *any* overlap in the lasso rectangle, will get selected.

Now, I have full selection working just fine.  The problem is with partial selection.  Everything I've done is too slow.  I don't have a spatial index/partition (octree or BVH, etc), so my next test is to create one to help more quickly cull out things that won't get selected.

In general, though, it seems at some point, I'm stuck with iterating through all the triangles of an object to see if any part of it overlaps with the lasso rectangle on screen.  In some cases, this will be very slow if the lasso selection is dragged to be large enough, such that no objects get culled out, and all must be checked for intersection with the rectangle.

Right now, I'm doing all rectangle/triangle intersection tests in JS (various ways of checking for intersection of an object with the rectangle), and no test is happening in a shader.

So I'm not really looking for help to speed up what I currently have, I am wanting to know if there are known ways of doing this that are relatively fast even for large numbers of highly detailed objects (meshes)?  I seemed to hit a wall, creatively, in thinking of a shader based approach.

Comment: I think spatial partitioning and creating bounding volumes for your objects/models and cpu based intersection is the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am gonna try, but I was hoping there was shader magic that could be done to do it faster.  I do use bounding volumes now, to speed things up, but eventually one must try triangle intersections it seems (that is, after the bounding volume checks, the code still has to get down to triangles, since testing only bounding volumes could lead to false positives).  So my fear is that, even with spatial partitioning, if the user quickly drags a pretty big rectangle, it will slow down still just to evaluate all those objects anyway.

Comment: You need to clarify what is objects of a model. Does that mean the vertices? Or a submodel like say a sphere (eyeball) in a complete human model. One thing to keep in mind is that you probably dont need perfect precision. For example, if you found that a vertex on a sphere is within your selection rect, then the sphere can be considered as selected and you dont need to process further. (triangle-something test is on a slow scale as far as pair-wise intersection tests go).

Comment: As far as GPU assist go, usually you sent a unique id of some sort along with the model's other attribute data. (like say vertices of object A all have 0 and object B all have 1 and so on) Then you do some processing in the shader using this unique id and you read the processed result back via `.readPixels`

Comment: So the model would be something like a building, and the objects would be individual parts like doors, windows, walls, etc.  Even checking just the vertices (which I did), is still too slow.  Ultimately, a spatial partition seems like it will, hopefully, speed things up for most use cases.